# GAMM model with spatial and temporal autocorrelattion

Tags: autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to integrate spatial and temporal autocorrelation to my GAMM model using packages mgcv and nlme. The following code runs, but I do not know, how to interpret the  “s(x, y)” command results. Can anyone explain it to me in a simple way?

I believe this should take account coordinates in my model. The model contains the following variables: I have 1 smoother, then coordinates, and 4 factor variables. I am using a quasi-poisson model, and I treat site ID (3 years data) as a random factor and have also an offset variable.

```
M1 <- gamm(sr~ s(smoother 1, fx=FALSE, k=-1, bs="cr")+ 
          s(x, y)+
         factor (variable 1)+
         factor (variable 2)+
         factor (variable 3)+
         factor (variable 4),
       family=quasipoisson,
       random=list(site id=~1),  
       data   = my dataset, offset=log(smoother 2))
```

This model is with a correlation structure, where I put the $x$ and $y$ coordinates inside, but it did not run unfortunately, although that can also be suitable for me. I also tried corAR1, but this correlation structure also did not work.

```
M2 <- gamm(sr~ s(smoother 1, fx=FALSE, k=-1, bs="cr")+ 
         factor (variable 1)+
         factor (variable 2)+
         factor (variable 3)+
         factor (variable 4),
       family=quasipoisson,
       correlation = corEXp(form = ~ x + y, nugget = T),
       random=list(site id =~1),  
       data   = my dataset, offset=log(smoother 2))
```

Can anyone comment on it in simple way? I am ecologist who does not have a very strong statistical background. But I am able to do this kind of R programming.

---

Thank you for your answer. Yes, there was a type in my code. I corrected it.

Answers for your questions.
Here is my actual code:

```
M <- gamm(sr~ s(AREA, bs="cr")+
         factor (type)+
         factor (year)+
         factor (ditch)+
         factor (bush)+
         factor (stones),
       family=quasipoisson,
       correlation = corExp(form = ~ x + y, nugget = T),
       random=list(fieldid=~1),
       data   = mydataset, offset=log(transect))
```

And the error message is:

```
Error in getCovariate.corSpatial(object, data = data): cannot have zero distances in "corSpatial"
```

What about if I add following code: `s(x, y)` ? Does this help me out? How to interprete it, because there are now not 1 but 2 smoothers together?

Comment: There's a typo: it is `corExp()` note the lowercase `x`. This looks OK, but you are stressing the fitting functions a lot with the second model: this is going `gamm()` -> `glmmPQL()` -> `lme()` and iterating backwards and forwards, a lot. Note you can leave out the `fx = false, k = -1` bits. If you can confirm the problem is not the typo in the correlation function, I'll look closer. Actual error messages and syntactically valid code would be nice: there is no way stuff like this is working as written: `list(site id =~1)`.

Comment: Also, I'd be surprised if you can fit this model with `gam()` directly now that it has a random effects spline basis (`bs = "re"`) and you can include Gaussian process spline basis terms that would probably model the spatial exponential correlation part of your model in the main model component not the covariance structure. I suspect that fitting via `gam()` will be less problematic than the `gamm()` -> `glmmPQL()` -> `lme()` trick...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, there was a type in my code. I corrected it.

Answers for your questions. Here is my actual code:`M <- gamm(sr~ s(AREA, bs="cr")+ factor (type)+ factor (year)+ factor (ditch)+ factor (bush)+ factor (stones), family=quasipoisson, correlation = corExp(form = ~ x + y, nugget = T), random=list(fieldid=~1), data = mydataset, offset=log(transect))` And the error message is: **Error in getCovariate.corSpatial(object, data = data) : cannot have zero distances in "corSpatial"**

Comment: What about if I add following code:`s(x, y)`? Does this help me out? How to interprate it, because there are now not 1 but 2 smoothers together?